# Take image of a chart.js from canvas and display it as an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

Display a base64 image of a chart.

I have a simple chart that I create. After it is created i want to take the base64 image of it and display it in html but I am not able to do that.

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gs8cpL70/1/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <img src="" id="coolImage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</body>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 15, 0.54)'
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
  label: {
      fontSize: 50
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}


var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
document.getElementById('coolImage').setAttribute('src', lineChart.toBase64Image());
```

I am not even sure if i am logic is correct because there could be a easier way to do this. I essentially want to display the image of the graph rather than the interactive line graph itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to wait until the chart has loaded before you get the image.

The only callback I could find with a quick search was the animation onComplete.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t42awnm8/) showing it working.

```
animation: {
  onComplete: function() {
    document.getElementById('coolImage').setAttribute('src', lineChart.toBase64Image());
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried that but got an `undefined` error on `lineChart` so didn't include it in my answer. +1!

Comment: wow, these are all very good answers. is there a way to only show the image instead of the actual chart. Or do i have to load the chart atleast once before showing the image? Only thing i could think of is loading the chart then getting the imageBase64 and hidding the chart and then showing the image.

Comment: @Dinero You can put `style="display:none"` on the canvas and you can still get the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the base64 from a canvas with `toDataURL()`. But in your case, the graphic probably hasn't been drawn completely before you try to read the canvas.

It works if I put the drawing code in a button:

HTML

```
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <img src="" id="coolImage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    <button id="create">Create image</button>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
var button = document.getElementById("create")

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);
    document.getElementById('coolImage').src = dataURL;
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j59xbf8d/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working, but [Kokodoko is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804650/3775731) that "the graphic probably hasn't been drawn completely before you try to read the canvas", so the image is simply of a blank canvas.

However, here are two ways I can immediately think of to set the image instead of manually pressing a button:

1. Turn off animation:

   ```
   options: {
     animation: {
       duration: 0 // general animation time
     },
     ...
   ```
2. Delay reading the canvas:

   ```
   setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById('coolImage').setAttribute('src', lineChart.toBase64Image());
   }, 1000); // execute after 1 second.
   ```

Comment: At first, I used the solution in the accepted answer and it worked - though I had several browser delays because I was debugging some PHP data to fill the chart.  Once I removed that, I also got 'undefined' on the chart.   Using setTimeout within the onComplete resolved it (though not sure why onComplete doesn't mean 'on complete'!)